# Gradually migrate from one SMTP server to another

Tags: postfix, smtp

I maintain an application that sends out a ton of e-mail on a daily basis. Soon, we will have to migrate to another SMTP-server for that, which has an ip address that has no reputation with respect to email delivery. So instead of just flipping the switch, I would like to start by sending a small percentage of all mail through the new server, and then gradually increase that percentage until we reach 100%.

It wouldn't be very hard to implement something in the application itself, but I would like to know if there is an easier, more reliable out-of-the-box-type solution for this.

My first thought was to use round-robin DNS for this, but the servers require different credentials, use different protocols (one uses SASL, the other doesn't) and even different port numbers, so I think that rules out the DNS based solution.

Is there any way, for example, to configure Postfix to send 1 out of x e-mails to relay host A and the rest to relay host B? Or perhaps a different MTA?

Comment: Not sure your architecture is clear here, so does the application store connection info for each SMTP box or does it send it to a local queue which then gets forwarded to an SMTP box for final delivery?

Comment: The application connects directly to a remote SMTP server at the moment.

Comment: "Warmed up" an IP address? That's a new one. I don't understand all those non-technical terms. Can you translate that into jargon?

Comment: When an ISP encounters lots of incoming email from a yet unknown address, it may block or throttle the sender. To establish a reputation as a legitimate email sender, you have to start with a small number of email addresses per day. It is explained in this article by Sendgrid: http://sendgrid.com/blog/how-to-warm-up-an-ip/

Comment: Aha. That looks like some term they just made up.

Comment: You say the application sends directly to a remote SMTP server. How does this square with the earlier statement that you would like a solution whereby `postfix` decides what happens with the messages ?

Comment: That's why I said "at the moment". It's something that is easy to change. Right now the application connects to a remote SMTP server, but I can easily change the settings so that it connects to a local server if that will make things easier.

Answer (score 2):

I would setup a load balancer in front of your old and new mail servers. Use a weighted round robin balancing algorithm and send 1% of your email to the new server to warm up the IPs. I've used this method on the past and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

Cronjob that changes configs?, use new server as mail-relay for 10 minutes each hour..

/etc/postfix/switch_to_new.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#Switch to new mail relay for a bitty...
postconf -e relayhost=[mail.mynewserver.com]:587
postfix reload
```

/etc/postfix/switch_back.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#delete relayhost
postconf -e relayhost=
postfix reload
```

then just cron between them as needed.. when you are up to 100% relayed, switch your app to the new server.